# Git submodule is returning blank?

Tags: git

I'm trying to use `git submodule update` and it's not returning anything, nor does any of the `git submodule` commands, and I have checked the `.gitmodules` file and it is correct?

I have no idea if git can be debugged or what, and it's really annoying.

There's no errors or anything, even when using `2>&1` on  the end which is really worrying.

Comment: if you write `git submodule` does the submodules appear?

Comment: Nope `kennydude@fluffy:~/Dev/boidapp$ git submodule
kennydude@fluffy:~/Dev/boidapp$ `

Comment: did you add the submodules like `git submodule add PATHTOGITREP`? there should appear some modules. nothing with `git submodule status`?

Comment: Yeah I did, and the .gitmodules file is correct. Nothing with status either

Comment: ok I have no idea what could happen but this should fix it, get the urls from your `.gitsubmodule` and `git submodule add URL` each one of those

Comment: Now it says it's already in the index. I'll just delete + reclone

Comment: well that should definitely fix it, good luck!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove any submodule entries from your `.git/config`. `git rm --cached path/to/submodule` to remove it from the tree. Make sure your working directory is clean. Now you can init the submodules:

```
git submodule init
```

All this does is populate your config with the urls that are in the `.gitmodules` file. Now you can populate the submodules:

```
git submodule update
```

if your submodules have nested submodules, add the recursive option:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

Init and update are separate for a good reason. You may want to have an alternate repository to store changes to you submodule.

Comment: When I run git submodule update --recursive, it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: i had to delete `.gitmodules` then `git rm --cached ./.gitmodules` after doing the steps you listed then did `git submodule add https://urlto.git` and it cloned the submodule into my parent repo

Answer (score 7):

It could be a late answer but in case someone needs it:

Just delete you blank submodule directory and run again

`git submodule add <https/ssh git link to your submodule`>

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, for me helped remove `.gitmodules` and commit this change. After add module again using `git submodule add`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help some googlers.

I had a similar problem where nothing would make the submodules appear.  The problem was that I added the submodule with an escaped windows path .\\Asset\\MyAsset instead of Asset/MyAsset

Check that your .gitmodules doesn't have a module with this style of path